# Change default storage location in camera in android using Java

Tags: android, camera, android-internal-storage

I want to toggle the default storage location to Device instead of sdcard in Camera using Android APIs. Please let me know if anyone has done this before.

Comment: You can give a path to camera for where to save but i don't thing it is possible to change default storage location of the "Camera app" by external intervention. For more info you can look into camera2 api, there are configurations for setting photo options.

Comment: Bear in mind that there are hundreds of different camera apps for Android, both pre-installed and user-installed. While some may offer an API for configuring them, most will not. Also, bear in mind that it is up to the camera app whether "default storage location" is configurable at all, let alone by third-party apps.